# Firefox location bar search: odd behaviour with Comodo firewall

Tags: firefox, firewall, search, comodo-firewall

I recently installed Comodo firewall, and it changed the behaviour of my Firefox location bar.

I used to type something there and it either redirected me to a google search page or it actually redirected me to the site I wanted at once: If I typed `'imdb cloud atlas'` it would redirect me to IMDB's page on Cloud Atlas, and the same would happen if I typed `'wiki'` or `'wikipedia'`, redirecting me to Wikipedia's page on it. Now, it redirects me [here](http://nxd.securedns.dns.com/main?).

I checked [this page](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/795446) and everything is according to what they describe, yet it doesn't seem to act the way it should. And there are no Comodo add-ons or extensions installed on Firefox.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off [Comodo Secure DNS](http://www.comodo.com/secure-dns/index.html):

[image: 1]

Switch back to either your ISP's DNS servers, or a public DNS resolution service such as the one provided by Google or OpenDNS.

Comment: The thing is that I installed Comodo on both my laptops with the exact same configurations, and this just happens in one of them. Doesn't this mean that it messed with something in Firefox itself?

Comment: Did you check if your DNS settings have changed?

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: The XP/Vista instructions are available via the Secure DNS link I provided above, else you can check the **Changing DNS server settings on Microsoft Windows 7** section on [this page](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using). If your PC is using Comodo's DNS, then your network adapter's ipv4 properties will look like the screenshot above.

Comment: I used the guide provided in your comment above. Thank you! And forget my first comment, it was behaving the same way on both laptops. BTW, what is the difference between Comodo's Secure DNS and Google's public DNS? I do not know much about these things... How much more secure is Comodo's?

Comment: Never used Comodo's service and don't trust Google. Stick to your ISP's DNS servers or use whichever public DNS you like, it's up to you really.